# Docker compose fails with 'COPY failed: stat usr/src/app/dist: file does not exist' - only on github actions

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nestjs, github-actions

I'm creating web application (angular + nest.js) and I'm trying to make multi stage build - I want to reduce size of docker image.

Angular build works good.

Nest.js one builds successfully on my pc using `docker compose build`, but fails on github actions with following error: `Status: COPY failed: stat usr/src/app/dist: file does not exist, Code: 1`

What can i do to fix it?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.13.1-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=development
RUN npm run build
COPY . .

FROM node:16.13.1-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY . .
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
EXPOSE 7000
CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

previous single stage Dockerfile (builds successfully):

```
FROM node:16.13.1-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
COPY . .
EXPOSE 7000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  backend:
    container_name: nestjs
    image: ghcr.io/<gh-nickname/repo-name>/backend  
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
    - 7000:7000
  frontend:
    container_name: angular
    image: ghcr.io/<gh-nickname/repo-name>/frontend
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
    - 8000:80
```

github workflow file:

```
name: Build and publish to github packages

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}

jobs:
  build-and-push-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    steps:
    - name: Checkout 
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Log in to the Container registry
      uses: docker/login-action@v1
      with:
        registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
        username: ${{ github.actor }}
        password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

    - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
      id: meta
      uses: docker/metadata-action@v3
      with:
        images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}

    - name: Build image
      run: docker compose build

    - name: Publish image
      run: docker compose push
```

Comment: Do you have a dist folder in the same directory as the Dockerfile? Is that directory included in the `.gitignore` and `.dockerignore`?

Comment: @BMitch `dist` is in the same directory as `Dockerfile`. directory is not included in `.gitignore` nor `.dockerignore`

Comment: Is the github repo public? If so, post the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solved it by moving `COPY . .` line before `RUN npm run build`

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following Dockerfile:

```html
FROM node:16.13.1-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --only=development
RUN npm run build
COPY . .

FROM node:16.13.1-alpine
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
EXPOSE 7000
CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

Comment: Yields the same error as before

Answer (score 0):

Caching multistage builds on CI Servers is not that easy as locally. You have to tell it where to get the layers from. As schema:

```
docker build --target build-image --cache-from=you/repo/backend:build-stage --tag you/repo/backend:build-stage

docker build --target prod-image --cache-from=you/repo/backend:build-stage --cache-from=you/repo/backend:prod-stage --tag you/repo/backend:prod-stage

docker push
```

So for GH Actions you can use the internal caching of GH and do something like:

```
steps:
- name: Build base image
        id: docker_build_base
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          file: Dockerfile
          push: false
          cache-from: |
            type=gha,scope=base
          cache-to: |
            type=gha,scope=base,mode=max
          target: base
          tags: you/repo/backend:build-stage

      - name: Build prod image
        id: docker_build_prod
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          file: Dockerfile
          push: true
          cache-from: |
            type=gha,scope=prod
            type=gha,scope=base
          cache-to: |
            type=gha,scope=prod,mode=max
          target: prod
          tags: you/repo/backend:prod-stage
```

Remark: It's showing you the right direction and no copy&paste solution. Please adjust as you need..